# Visualizing overlay of 6 point data sets using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, overlay, visualisation

I have a visualization question. Using ArcMap 10.6, I would like to overlay six point datasets in a way that synergies and differences can be quickly seen by people who have no idea about GIS applications and are not use to work with digital maps.
My current idea would be to simply use different symbols and colors for the six datasets and display this on a map. This representation could be combined with a simple density analysis (kernel density) (see figure). I am not sure if correlations would be understandable.

[image]

Nonetheless, I would like to ask if there are more "understandable" ways to display six point datasets overlaid so that the differences and similarities can be quickly identified by anyone?

Information about the points: The points represent potential locations for new trees that were freely chosen in a group discussion (six group discussion results). Each point record could contain between 3 to 50 points. First, all groups should be compared with each other.

Comment: Is the point map on the left a real example of the data? An answer to this question will require more information about the number of data points overall that need display, and perhaps something about the nature of the data - do differences between groups need to be emphasised?

Comment: Information about the points: The points represent potential locations for new trees that were freely chosen in a group discussion (six group discussion results). Each point record could contain between 3 to 50 points. First, all groups should be compared with each other.

Comment: Looking at the kernel density map, all I get from it is the level of agreement in where to place the trees, without any ability to ask follow-up questions. And I'm understanding that much because I can see that the green places in the kernel density map correspond to places with lots of points in the map on the left (without the left map textual explanations would be needed). I think you should be thinking about what kinds of comparisons and takeaways you want the readers of the map to be making.

Comment: Are you wanting to show some sort of analysis based upon the choices by the actual groups? Group C has only 3 locations whilst group B is in 5 location. Your density map hides any differentiation between groups. What is it you want to show: difference between group choices or difference between tree locations regardless of group?

Comment: The KD map does not add much. I can see clearly what people want from the point map on the right. Add some transparency to the symbols due to overlapping points.

Comment: @Hornbydd "What is it you want to show: difference between group choices or difference between tree locations regardless of group?" -->The groups should see differences between the groups and discuss them. At the same time, locations should be found that are preferred by the majority. I will now probably just take the left map, because simple is probably the best solution here. Thanks for the feedback